# Date filter with template not applying filtering (PrimeNG Table)

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable, primeng-calendar

I'm developing a SPA with PrimeNG's table to display records, and each column has a filter for its data.

One of them is a date record, which comes as ISO string and is converted to a Date object before being fed to the table itself.

I need the date format to be "dd/MM/yyyy", and by default the p-columnFilter for date works with "MM/dd/yyyy", so I'm using the pTemplate of filter to customize the format in the calendar.

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-col [ngForOf]="columns">
  <th *ngIf="col.type !== 'date'" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
    {{col.header}}
    <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
  </th>
  <th *ngIf="col.type === 'date'" class="obe-table__date-header" [pSortableColumn]="col.field" [attr.rowspan]="2">
    {{col.header}}
    <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
    <p-columnFilter type="date" [field]="col.field" display="menu">
      <ng-template pTemplate="filter">
        <p-calendar dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>
      </ng-template>
    </p-columnFilter>
  </th>
</ng-template>
```

Then, when displaying the filter UI and clicking on "Apply", it acts as if it doesn't register the value. I was thinking about me missing an [ngModel] binding in the calendar, but I also tried that  to no success.

[image: Screen recording of the problem. Filter doesn't apply.]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to the function is missing :

```
 (onSelect)="filter($event)"
```

don't forget in the ng-template:

```
 let-filter="filterCallback"
```

it gives this :

```
 <p-columnFilter type="date" [field]="col.field" display="menu">
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-filter="filterCallback">
    <p-calendar dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" (onSelect)="filter($event)"></p- 
     calendar>
  </ng-template>
 </p-columnFilter>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I finally switched to a workaround, displaying the filter as row instead as the menu view, and using custom logic to control the clearing and selecting functionalities. But this definitely was missing from my first try :) Marking it is accepted.